# Can I invoke a static function from another compilation unit by using its address?

Tags: c, static-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static function access in other files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182598/static-function-access-in-other-files)

IIRC, a static function is not visible outside of own "compilation unit", which I think is a .C file.

Can I pass its address as a parameter to a function in another unit so that the second unit will later invoke the first unit's static function as a callback?

I am guessing that the "visibility" of the static function is its visibility to the linker, so that, while I cannot directly invoke a static function of unit1.c in unit2.c, I can pass its address and invoke it by address.

Can anyone confirm that? Sorry, my C is a bit rusty these days. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2182598/1410711) might be helpful....

Comment: Certainly not a recommended technique.  But yes, you can absolutely do it.  Just use a function pointer.  The tricky part is getting access to the address, so you can initialize the pointer. :)

Comment: Yes, there's nothing that could stop you from doing that. And there is nothing non-recommended about it ... in fact, it's a recommended technique for doing callbacks, which should be static (file-local).

Comment: Also, there's nothing tricky about it: just pass the name of the function as a parameter; the name (without parentheses) represents the function address.

Comment: Why the heck would anyone vote to close this question? edit: ah, I see, a duplicate ... but this is a far better stated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call static function in that way